# Template method calling template method of another class doesn't want to compile

Tags: c++11

I've got issues with templates.
A class `Entity` contains a `std::map` of types (`const std::type_info*`) and `Components` (`std::shared_ptr<Component>`). One of these components can be a `BehaviorSet`, which has a similar map of components. But these components are `Behavior`, a class derived from `Component`.

At first it worked without the Behaviors and BehaviorSet. I was using the Entity to add, get and remove its components using their type (hence forcing the uniqueness of each component).
When I added the `BehaviorSet` stuff, it got weird. I'd really like to find out why can't it compile.
It looks like the compiler is trying to cast classes it shouldn't.

**Q.hpp**

---

```
#include <map>      // std::map
#include <memory>   // std::shared_ptr
#include <typeinfo> // std::type_info

class Component {
public:
    Component() {}
    virtual ~Component() {}
};

class Behavior : public Component {
public:
    Behavior() {}
    virtual ~Behavior() {}
};

class BehaviorSet : public Component {
protected:
    std::map<const std::type_info*, std::shared_ptr<Behavior>> behaviors;
public:

    // Get a pointer to a behavior by its type
    template <typename T>
    T* getBehavior()
    {
        if (behaviors.count(&typeid(T)) != 0)                       // If there's a key for type T ..
            return dynamic_cast<T*>(behaviors[&typeid(T)].get());   // Get the pointer of shared_ptr and cast Behavior to T*            
        return nullptr;                                             // Return NULL on Behavior not found
    }

    // Add a behavior by pointer
    template <typename T>
    void addBehavior(T* behavior)
    {
        if (behaviors.count(&typeid(T)) != 0) return;                // If there's a key, we can't add
        behaviors[&typeid(T)] = std::shared_ptr<Behavior>(behavior); // else we can add the behavior to the map
    }

    // Add a behavior by type
    template <typename T, typename ... Args>
    void addBehavior(Args && ... args)
    {
        addBehavior(new T(std::forward<Args>(args) ...));           // Call addBehavior on a newly created behavior
    }
};


class Entity {
protected:
    std::map<const std::type_info*, std::shared_ptr<Component>> components;
public:

    // Get pointer to component by its type
    template <typename T>
    T* getComponent()
    {
        if (std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value) {
            // Hoping there is a BehaviorSet
            return getComponent<BehaviorSet>()->getBehavior<T>();
        }
        if (components.count(&typeid(T)) != 0) return nullptr;  // Return NULL on Component not found
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(components[&typeid(T)].get());  // Get the pointer of shared_ptr and cast Component to T*

    }

    // Add a component by pointer
    template <typename T>
    void addComponent(T* component)
    {
        // If there's already a component of this type, don't even try to add
        if (components.count(&typeid(T)) != 0) return;

        // If it's derived from Behavior, add to BehaviorSet component
        if (std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value)
        {
            // Hoping there is a BehaviorSet
            getComponent<BehaviorSet>()->addBehavior<T>(component);
        }
        // It's not derived from Behavior, add it to the component map
        else
        {
            components[&typeid(T)] = std::shared_ptr<Component>(component);
        }
    }

    // Add a component by type
    template <typename T, typename ... Args>
    void addComponent(Args && ... args)
    {
        addComponent(new T(std::forward<Args>(args) ...));
    }
};



class CBehavior : public Behavior {
protected:
    unsigned int value;
public:
    CBehavior(unsigned int arg) : value(arg) {}
};
```

Now in main, I'm adding a `BehaviorSet` and a `CBehavior` :

**main.cpp**

---

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Entity entity;
    entity.addComponent<BehaviorSet>();
    entity.addComponent<CBehavior>(1233);
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile and my g++ tells me this :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/memory:82,
                 from src/Q.hpp:2,
                 from src/game/main.cpp:45:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of ‘std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = BehaviorSet; _Tp = Behavior; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:113:32:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = BehaviorSet; _Tp = Behavior]’
src/Q.hpp:36:25:   required from ‘void BehaviorSet::addBehavior(T*) [with T = BehaviorSet]’
src/Q.hpp:77:4:   required from ‘void Entity::addComponent(T*) [with T = BehaviorSet]’
src/Q.hpp:90:3:   required from ‘void Entity::addComponent(Args&& ...) [with T = BehaviorSet; Args = {}]’
src/game/main.cpp:50:35:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:871:39: erreur: cannot convert ‘BehaviorSet*’ to ‘Behavior*’ in initialization
         : _M_ptr(__p), _M_refcount(__p)
```

If it matters, I'm using g++ 4.9.2 on up-to-date archlinux.

Thank you very much for your help, and I hope my question is clear enough :)

Edit: I think I've reduced all that I could in the code.

Comment: Wall of code! Can you please remove everything which is not related to the error? This means you'll keep trying to remove stuff and checking that the error is still there, until you arrive at the [minimal reproducing code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh sorry. I'll crunch that wall :)

Comment: I can't tell whether this segmentation fault is _with_ the answers below, or from before them. This is why we do not vastly alter questions after-the-fact. I have reverted your change.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember that. Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the last issues here (mainly thanks to Daniel Frey).

**First try**

In the `addComponent()` function I first changed `getComponent<BehaviorSet>()` to a direct access to the `components` map (`dynamic_cast<BehaviorSet*> components[&typeid(BehaviorSet)].get())`). It worked then. So that's what lead me to think the problem was in the `getComponent()` method.

**Second try**

I tried to use the same trick for `getComponent()` as the one for `addComponent()`. Since `std::enable_if<bool condition>::type` is equivalent to `void` if the condition is true, It couldn't be used directly. The workaround is to make to other functions (`protected` if you want) to retrieve the component in a pointer to pointer passed in argument and returning the component "updated". They both have a `void` return type so the `std::enable_if` trick works here.

A pointer to pointer to Component must be used because the value of the pointer to Component wouldn't be changed in the `getComponent()` scope.

```
template <typename T>
T* getComponent() {
    T* component = nullptr;
    retrieveComponent(&component);
    std::cout << std::to_string(component != nullptr) << std::endl;
    return component;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value>::type
retrieveComponent(T** component) {
    if (components.count(&typeid(BehaviorSet)) == 0) return;
    *component = getComponent<BehaviorSet>()->getBehavior<T>();
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value>::type
retrieveComponent(T** component) {
    *component = dynamic_cast<T*>(components[&typeid(T)].get());
}
```

*Edit* :
**Third Try**

---

That last version is more fashionable. Daniel Frey pointed out that enable_if had a template parameter to specify the return type. It's quite nicer then to use it to return `T*` for `getComponent()` !

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value, T*>::type
getComponent() {
    if (components.count(&typeid(BehaviorSet)) == 0) return nullptr;
    return getComponent<BehaviorSet>()->getBehavior<T>();
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value, T*>::type
getComponent() {
    if (components.count(&typeid(T)) == 0) return nullptr;
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(components[&typeid(T)].get());
}
```

**Conclusion**

---

I seriously think about *not* doing this entity-component-system architecture I've dreamt of. But the base framework is here so I won't give up now :/

Comment: [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) has a second parameter which is the returned type, defaulted to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you try to instantiate a method even if the code is never executed. You seem to think that the compiler will not try to instantiate code based on the result of `std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value`, but in reality, the code will always be instantiated, e.g., the code in both the `if` and the `else` part.

To solve your problem, try using different implementations for both cases that are separated at compile-time. For example, this might work:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value>::type
addComponent(T* component)
{
    if (components.count(&typeid(T)) != 0) return;
    getComponent<BehaviorSet>()->addBehavior<T>(component);
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Behavior, T>::value>::type
addComponent(T* component)
{
    if (components.count(&typeid(T)) != 0) return;
    components[&typeid(T)] = std::shared_ptr<Component>(component);
}
```

Comment: "the code will always be instantiated, e.g., the code in both the if and the else part." I was expecting that kind of behavior from the compiler :/
I didn't know of the existence of std::enable_if, that looks damn great for my purpose :) I'm trying this right now.